# Is there a good server side javascript based rest API testing framework?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, serverside-javascript

I would like to test the external endpoints of a rest api written in java but I would like to run tests from javascript for the possibility of sharing js code and maybe the testing framework with our client web application.  Is there a good library out there to make this easier so I don't have to reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use restler as the http client

https://github.com/danwrong/restler

and mocha for TDD/BDD

http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/

Writing a test is very simple there is almost no boilerplate involved even though it is not actually a framework per se

```
test('/authenticate service should authenticate user', function(done) {

    var myService = service.getLocator().authenticate;
    var params = {username: "...", password: "..."};
    service.postJson(myService.host, '/authenticate', params, function(data, response) {
        data.username.should.eql('...');
        done();
    });


});
```

Comment: Hmm this does look like a promising combo, I didn't think of combining the http client with another framework duh

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet but the node.js version of VCR https://github.com/elcuervo/vcr.js looks promising.

Although I would just stub the responses if it's not too complex.